# Configure IntelliJ project when importing when importing a Gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Is there a way to import a Gradle Java project into IntelliJ 2017.2.x and apply some settings like

- code style
- vcs settings

from the Gradle `build.gradle` on project level?

I noticed that e.g. the Grails Framework uses the [idea-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/energizedwork/idea-gradle-plugins) but this only works in combination with the Gradle task `idea`.

```
gradlew idea
```

I don't want to generate IntelliJ project files using a Gradle task. I would like IntelliJ to fetch the settings from the build file whenever I import the `build.gradle` file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik no. You can only set in `build.gradle` what is supported by the DSL that then also is understood by the IDEA integration. There is no way to set arbitrary settings this way.

To do this, as you already found out, you need to hook into the IDEA project file generation and generate the settings you want like code style settings and VCS settings (I do both for our projects and more) and then use the `idea` task to generate the project files.

You can also configure IDEA to automatically run some Gradle task before refreshing the project, so you can make IDEA automatically run the `idea` task before refreshing and this should work then. The initial IDEA setup to do this though has either to be generated with `idea`, set-up manually by all devs or configured once and then checked in. But if you check-in the IDEA files, you can of course also simply check-in the code-style and VCS settings. Most of the IDEA project files are meant to be checked in anyway. Just some like the workspace file are meant to be developer-specific and thus excluded from being checked in.